# SafeAreaView height calculation for iPhoneX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a requirement where I have to position the container below header with `position: 'absolute'` and top based on the header height which I can get it from `import { Header } from 'react-navigation-stack'` and then `Header.HEIGHT`.

Everything works perfect expect iPhone X like devices where it has some extra pullover of device due to which it is taking some extra space and thus I am not able to place the container properly, so I want to calculate that height so that I can add it up if it present to the position top value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for some generic solution and finally I am using 'react-native-status-bar-height' to find out the status bar height and then adding it to the actual navigation header height for positioning

Answer (score 1):

Normally the height of the status bar as below,

- `44` for safe iPhone X
- `30` for unsafe iPhone X
- `20` for other iOS devices
- `StatusBar.currentHeight` for Android

Also you can use an external library like [react-native-iphone-x-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iphone-x-helper) to design your app for the iPhone X, XS, XS Max & XR or [react-native-safe-area-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context) to handle safe area.

Hope this helps you feel free for doubts.

Comment: I am looking for some concrete solution and more specifically I need the height for iPhone X so that I can able to add it up on the positioning value

Comment: @SaikatSaha what you mean by ```height for iPhone X```?

Comment: I mean height of pullover

Comment: @SaikatSaha that is what I mention in my answer. iPhone X safe area height is ```44```

Comment: That is a hard coded one, suppose in future some company launch a similiar type of phone with different resolution on Android, then my code will break, that's why I need some generic solution